# Convert font to all web font types

Tags: python, css, fonts, webfonts

I've been reading this morning about fonts because I need to use a particular font with css.

It seems rather complicated to expect someone to provide the right font types, so I got to looking at how one can convert from one type to another.

I've found several python packages that seem to work with fonts. This one seems to be the most promising:  https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools but I haven't found any examples of conversion to web formats from other formats.

Is it straight forward to detect a font type and then export the other types for inclusion with css?

An example would be great from an otf or even better from an unknown font type to ttf, otf, eot, woff and woff2

Comment: Why the downvote?  Seems like a valid question on how to use tools to convert fonts?

Answer (score 2):

You can to use online tool [fontsquirel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) - this tool allow to convert otf/ttf fonts into **TrueType, WOFF, WOFF2, EOT Lite, EOT Compressed, SVG**.

Please notice: this tool allows to convert **only free fonts**.

Comment: I am looking for an offline solution that can be scripted